# iptables: Block internet, but allow local connections

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn

I got myself a VPN account and want to ensure that everything is using the VPN connection. So I started with iptables and decided to block everything except for the tun0 network device. Immediately after executing the shell script my SSH connection drops ;)

Here is the conent of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables -t nat --flush
iptables -t nat --delete-chain

iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i lo
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o lo

iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -s 192.168.178.0/24 -i eth0
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -d 192.168.178.0/24 -o eth0

iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -s 185.102.219.47/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1443
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -d 185.102.219.47/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1443

iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i tun0
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o tun0
```

This allows me to stay connected using SSH but I can still ping and surf in the web, even when tun0 is not connected. There is also ipv6 enabled on the rpi, maybe now everything using ipv6 is still allowed?

My goal is to allow everything on the local network, but only allow connections to the VPN server. Internet access should only be possible using the tun0 device.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you disable IPv6?

Comment: Why don't you create a rule to drop 443 and 80?

Comment: i didn't say a single word about http/https....I am disabling ipv6 now, maybe the firewill will give any results that I can understand...

Comment: Is your VPN connection routed to the internet? If so, probably your VPN client changes your default route to it. Check your VPN client documentation about client routing.